# Save image to SD card from fullscreen activity with Image View

Tags: android, imageview

I have an Activity with its layout having only an Image View, and I want to make it when the user clicks the image, a dialog to appear with button to save the image, but the dialog is not appearing, whats wrong?

```
    public class ShowImage extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivShowImage);
        String imgUrlPortrait = "some URL";
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgUrlPortrait, iv);
    }

    public void saveImg(View v) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        db.setNeutralButton("Save Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "img" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                boolean success = false;
                try {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved to SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                AlertDialog dlg = db.create();
                dlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dlg.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the layout

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ivShowImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:onClick="saveImg"
    tools:context=".ShowImage" >

</ImageView>
```

and here is the activity in the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.package.ShowImage"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forget to set a listener on your ImageView. Try to add this at the end of your onCreate:

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        saveImg(iv);    
    }
});
```

Comment: nope its not that, I tried already and still not working... and right now the onClick is defined in the xml, this saveImg method

Answer (score 0):

try `android:clickable="true"` for ImageView like this

```
 <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ivShowImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:onClick="saveImg"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".ShowImage" >

</ImageView>
```

Comment: are you getting any error. Make sure that saveImg() is called or not using log.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code to show the Alert Dialog wasnt placed properly, now it works like this

```
public class ShowImage extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivShowImage);
        String imgUrlPortrait = "some URL";
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgUrlPortrait, iv);
    }

    public void saveImg(View v) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        db.setNeutralButton("Save Image", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "img" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                boolean success = false;
                try {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                    outStream.flush();
                    outStream.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved to SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
                AlertDialog dlg = db.create();
                dlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dlg.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it working now? Can you please show what was the problem?

Comment: @fWd82  sorry I dont remember, this is from 2013

Comment: -_- Oho. Just wondering if that helped, there should be some `accepted` answer. But anyhow. :)